# howto hide firefox add-on popup initiate by selenium rc?

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, selenium, selenium-rc

everytime i test my selenium test, the instant of firefox will popup and show page of selenium rc. It's ok and cool. But i have problem. For every test i also have to see a firefox's page pop up and shown selenium plugin have been add to firefox.

is there any way to configure selenium so it initiate firefox without a popup page cause after a hundred test, it start to irritate me ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is a duplicate of another SO question, as I feel like I've answered it before, but I can't find it. If I do subsequently find it then I will update my answer.

You need to set the `extensions.lastAppVersion` preference to match the version of Firefox that you're launching. Otherwise you will generally have an additional tab in Firefox and the Addons manager popup.

You may need to configure Selenium to use a custom Firefox profile in order to make this change.

Comment: i have use custom profile. and i assume extensions.lastappversion is firefox config(about:config) isn't it ?

Comment: That's correct. Alternatively you can directly modify the `prefs.js` file in your custom profile directory.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the extensions.rdf file from profile directory will fix this issue . I have created a separate profile for Selenium tests, which is only used for Selenium Tests. I would love to hear if there is other way around . My "extensions.lastAppVersion" is updated and reflects the current browser version therefore the above trick does not work for me .

Remember, invoking  selenium by user will re-create extensions.rdf file, therefore I prefer to keep separate  profile for Selenium

Answer (score 1):

Having found this answer and had a go, I found that merging the Extensions.rdf and extensions.ini file from the temporary profile created in a Selenium session and putting that into your Custom Profile directory solves this problem.

When merging extensions.ini, be careful to avoid getting the pathnames wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

From the address bar type “about:config” and add/update the following: 
- `extensions.update.notifyUser (type=boolean; value=false)` 
- `extensions.newAddons (type=boolean; value=false)`

 It worked for me.